# Implementing a member function of a class nested in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm implementing template member functions in a .cpp, and understand the limitations involved (only going to template this class to one type at a time).  Everything is working fine, except this one case.  While I have gotten constructors for nested classes to work, I'm having trouble with any other nested class member function.  For reference, I'm compiling with VC++ 11.

In .h:

```
template<typename T> class TemplateClass
{
 class NestedClass
 {
  NestedClass();

  bool operator<(const NestedClass& rhs) const;
 };
};
```

In .cpp:

```
//this compiles fine:
template<typename T>
TemplateClass<T>::NestedClass::NestedClass()
{
 //do stuff here
}

//this won't compile:
template<typename T>
bool TemplateClass<T>::NestedClass::operator<(const TemplateClass<T>::NestedClass& rhs) const
{
 //do stuff here

 return true;
}

template class TemplateClass<int>; //only using int specialization
```

edit:  Here's the errors, all pointing to the `operator<` implementation line

error C2059: syntax error : 'const'
error C2065: 'rhs' : undeclared identifier
error C2072: 'TemplateClass::NestedClass::operator <' : initialization of a function
error C2470: 'TemplateClass::NestedClass::operator <' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Comment: What is the error (if any)?

Comment: @David Added my errors.  This is in VC++ 11, if it makes any difference.

Comment: @user173342, it does make a difference. My sympathies.

Comment: @user173342 FYI `NestedClass` is in scope as a parameter type. Try `bool TemplateClass<T>::NestedClass::operator<(const NestedClass& rhs) const`

Comment: @Pubby You got it!  Turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NestedClass` is in scope as a parameter type and so you can try this:

```
 bool TemplateClass<T>::NestedClass::operator<(const NestedClass& rhs) const
```

MSVC is probably buggy on the first version.